# pydantic v2 migrate json_loads, json_dumps

Tags: pydantic

Pydantic v2 has dropped `json_loads` (and `json_dumps`) config settings (see [migration guide)](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#changes-to-config)

However, there is no indication by what replaced them. Does anyone have pointers on these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pydantic v2 those methods have been replaced by `.model_dump_json()` and `.model_validate_json()`. See the following example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str 


m = Model(a="1", b="2")
data = m.model_dump_json()
print(type(data))

m_new = Model.model_validate_json(data)
print(type(m_new))
```

Which prints:

```
<class 'str'>
<class '__main__.Model'>
```

Dumping a model to a dict with json encoding instead, works like:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str 


m = Model(a="1", b="2")
data = m.model_dump(mode="json")
print(type(data))

m_new = Model.model_validate(data)
print(type(m_new))
```

Which prints:

```
<class 'dict'>
<class '__main__.Model'>
```

I hope this helps!